# CASE formula reading blanks

Tags: formula-field

I'm trying to get this formula field to display the correct field for the correct year. The values of the picklist at 2014, 2013, 2012. The related fields are just numbers. There are no syntax errors but it's returning nothing - not even the else result field.

```
CASE( Commercial_Sales_Year__c, "2014", 
of_commercial_customers_2014__c , "2013", 
of_commercial_customers_2013__c , "2012", 
of_commercial_customers_2012__c, 0)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give example of the data you are expecting in `Commercial_Sales_Year__c`, `of_commercial_customers_2014__c`, `of_commercial_customers_2013__c` and `of_commercial_customers_2012__c`. Also provide the expected output of the formula

Comment: What is the return type of your formula? Text or number?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've got your CASE parameters right?  Salesforce defines CASE as follows:

```
CASE(expression,​value1, result1, value2,​ result2,...,​ else_result)
```

You have a mix of variables and strings that makes it look like you are trying to do

```
CASE(expression1,result1, expression2, result2, ... else_result)
```

Also, your else_result parameter is a number, All the other items that look like results are strings.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: I think the intention is that the formula should return various fields from the same object depending on the year in the Commercial_Sales_Year__c picklist field. So as long as fields such as of_commercial_customers_2014__c are numbers this should work.